# Is an XSS attack possible under these constraints?

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser, xss

The output is:

```
<img src="http://example.com/[input]"
     oncontextmenu="openUrl('http://example.com/[input]')">
```

Where **[input]** is the user input, which is sanitised through this function:

```
a => {
  a = String(a);
  a = this.replaceAll(a, "&", "&amp;");
  a = this.replaceAll(a, '"', "&quot;");
  a = this.replaceAll(a, "'", "&#39;");
  a = this.replaceAll(a, "<", "&lt;");
  return a = this.replaceAll(a, ">", "&gt;")
}
```

in other words, we seemingly can't break out or use quotes of any kind?

Is an XSS attack possible at all under these constraints? Or is it possible to redirect the user to any domain besides example.com? Or indeed, load an image from (or make a request to) evil.com? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so. But as an aside, couldn't your whole `replaceAll()` code be, itself, replaced with `a = a.encodeHTML();`?

Comment: Depends on where the value is reused, but the used sanitizer doesn't remove encoded characters like `\u00`. It's also very easy to override the entire argument of the inline listener with a new content using the DevTools.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There is no `.encodeHTML()` method in JS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a XSS vulnerability.

While you do escape the HTML attribute syntax fine (so that nothing can break out of the `src` and `oncontextmenu` values), it does lack

- validation of the example.com path. [`src` attribute values can be malicious on their own](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135513/what-could-an-img-src-xss-do), and if someone gets the visitor to load `http://example.com/logout`, `http://example.com/user-content?from=eve&file=bad-icon` or `http://example.com/redirect.php?target=evil.com/`, they might have won. Yes, this depends on who controls example.com and possible vulnerabilities in there, but getting the victim to load certain URLs is part of many attacks.
- escaping of the JS string content! Let's say `input` is `'.replace(/.*/,'evil.com')+'`, you will end up with `oncontextmenu="openUrl('http://example.com/'.replace(/.*/,'evil.com')+'')"`. The HTML entities won't help you there - `&apos;` in the attribute becomes `'` in the script.